# Facebook application links result in "Sorry, this page isn't available"

Tags: facebook

All of app links that start with "http://apps.facebook.com/AppID#" are giving me 4oh4 error link page which states that the page is not available. To be exact, I've copied & pasted the exact error it gives me below.

> Sorry, this page isn't available, The link you followed may be broken, or the page may have been removed.

I have tried using http://apps.facebook.com/namespace here in which this gives me blank white page!

Could this be in correlation of today's facebook mass disabling of app links? I just don't know but I want to know if other people are having same issues as me and know a solution. Or if this is somethign we gotta wait out for facebook to fix? Please help! Thank you.